# Setting file on S3 as read-only with Boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

How do you set a key on S3 using Boto so you won't accidentally overwrite it later? Is there a way to make it read-only or at least give you some sort of error if you eventually try to write to the same key again.

I've tried changing ACLs, both the key's and the bucket's, and nothing seemed to make any difference.

When I remove the `write` permission using DragonDisk (so it becomes `<Policy: roddds (owner) = READ, roddds (owner) = READ_ACP>`), but if I run `keyfile.set_contents_from_string()` it changes it back to full control.

I am accessing the bucket as the owner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The owner of a `bucket` or `object` will always have `FULL_CONTROL`, even with the most restrictive ACL `private`: see [S3 ACL Overview](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ACLOverview.html).  If that were not the case, how would an owner ever delete an object that he or she set to read only?

Check if a key exists before writing it to S3:

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection 
from boto.s3.key import Key

conn = S3Connection(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
bucket = conn.get_bucket(MY_BUCKET_NAME)
key = Key(bucket, MY_KEY_NAME)

if not bucket.get_key(key.name):
    key.set_contents_from_string("foo")
```

Alternatively, you can try setting up a different AWS user for your Boto program with `READ` access to your bucket.  Then when you create the key (using your owner credentials), set the ACL to `authenticated-read`.

Answer (score 0):

An owner does have access rights that cannot be taken away.  However, there are things you can do to protect yourself from yourself.

First, enable versioning on the bucket.  Then, even if you do delete an object it isn't really deleted unless you explicitly delete the object versionId.  You can still find older versions and restore them.  You can find more information on bucket versioning [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Versioning.html)

Secondly, if you have objects on S3 that you really, really don't want to delete accidentally, check out the MFA Delete feature.  This is a something you can enable on a versioned bucket.  Once enabled, to delete any object you have to actually supply a token from a MFA device.  See [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMFADelete.html) for more details.